# Sencha chart: Offset for max and min value of axes

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have an app with a cartesian chart like this: 
[image] Rightnow the minimum and maximum values of a serie are displayed on the top or the bottom of the axis, but what I would like to achieve is having an offset beween the end of the axis and the maximum value of the serie.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use innerPadding: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/kjl

```
new Ext.chart.CartesianChart({
        animate: true,
        innerPadding: {top: 10, left: 50, right: 10, bottom: 10},
        store: {
          fields: ['name', 'data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4', 'data5'],
          data: [
              {'name':'metric one', 'data1':27, 'data2':12, 'data3':14, 'data4':8, 'data5':13},
              {'name':'metric two', 'data1':7, 'data2':8, 'data3':16, 'data4':10, 'data5':3},
              {'name':'metric three', 'data1':5, 'data2':2, 'data3':14, 'data4':12, 'data5':7},
              {'name':'metric four', 'data1':2, 'data2':14, 'data3':6, 'data4':1, 'data5':23},
              {'name':'metric five', 'data1':27, 'data2':38, 'data3':36, 'data4':13, 'data5':33}
          ]
        }
```